# Is there a solution for parker's square?

Tags: square-numbers, magic-square

From [wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square#): Mathematician Matt Parker attempted to create a 3x3 magic square using square numbers in a YouTube video on the Numberphile channel. His failed attempt is known as the Parker Square.

I wonder , if there's a solution or proof that there is none?

Comment: You would have found the answer by actually watching that Numberphile episode ...

Comment: Direct link to the time in the video when Parker states that this is an open problem: https://youtu.be/aOT_bG-vWyg?t=36

Comment: Here's a some of the reason why it's so difficult to prove/disprove.A magic square of squares could be transformed into 8 elliptic curve solutions (and similarly such elliptic curve solutions could be turned into a MSOS). This relates the problem to more high-level mathematics. For example, some possible diagonals, rows, and columns of the MSOS can be ruled out if the Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer conjecture, a millennial problem, is proven.

Comment: @ChristianWoll fascinating... may i ask what is MSOS?

Comment: @athos Magic Square of Squares :) More about elliptic curves and square numbers: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/ugradnumthy/congnumber.pdf

Comment: @ChristianWoll thanks for the explanation!

Comment: I read somewhere last year that there was a formula for finding $3\times 3$ magic squares, where each entry is a squared number and no rules are relaxed apart from how one diagonal does not add up to the magic constant, however I cannot find it. All I remember was that by letting each entry equal $n_1^2, n_2^2,\ldots, n_9^2$, the value $n$ was a polynomial expression containing all degrees up to $4$ and a single indeterminate $k$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an open problem.  No example is known; nor is a proof that there is none.

[Open Problem Garden](http://www.openproblemgarden.org/op/magic_square_of_squares) says:

> This question was first asked in 1984 by Martin LaBar and popularized in 1996 by Martin Gardner, who offered \$100 to the first person to construct such a square. In 2005 Christian Boyer offered €1,000 and a bottle of champagne for a solution to a somewhat easier problem. For a review of the history of research, see […]. For basic facts about the anticipated $ 3\times 3 $ magic square of squares, see […].

[Some discussion is given on mathpages.com](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath417/kmath417.htm).

Comment: Ok, so it's still open...